# Correct verb for compound sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is below sentence gramatically correct:

```
Injustice and misinformation are rising everywhere.
```

Or should I use 'is' instead of 'are'. Why?

Comment: It depends on if you treat the two things as a unit or not. (*Where* ***is*** *my mortar and pestle* versus *where* ***are*** *my shoes and socks*.) Most likely these are two separate things. However, it might *sound* better if you started the sentence with *both* so that the meaning is clear.

Comment: By the way, the sentence is simple, not  compound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the word "and" look at it as you would "+".
so injustice + misinformation = 2

the verb should be the plural *are*